# csv file into a table- Python programming

Tags: python, json, dataframe, csv

I have a csv file as the following:

```
 1.A B C D E  
 2.fish, hen, cow,goat,{"Plant":{"fruit":{"name":Apple},{"Type":sweet}}}  
 3.fish,hen, cow,goat,{"Plant":{"fruit":{"name":Pineapple},{"Type":sour}}}
```

where `1.` is the header and the rest are the rows. I want to extract the last column which is a JSON into:

```
 1. name type
 2. Apple Sweet
 3. Pineapple Sour
```

Can anyone please help me. I tried to delete up to the last column and read the JSON file but its not working.

Comment: It could be difficult if the json is not escaped about commas and other characters that could be read the csv parser, and by the other hand you don't have commas in the first line, so you should skip it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Import csv and use csv.dictreader. Once you load the data into a dict, you will find extracting any data to be very easy.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your input helped me alot.